# Gráfico Circular para nalise de correlação em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde:

Sou iniciante na linguagem python. Gostaria de saber onde eu posso encontrar material de estudo para gerar gráficos circulares para análise de correlação em python semelhante ao da figura abaixo (na linguagem R).Eu procurei na documentação do matplotlib mas não encontrei.

Grato pela atenção.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HFYC.png)[Fonte: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]